# Is it normal that (some) HTML entities are breaking the XSL engine?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, domdocument, html-entities

I have a dynamically generated XML document made with PHP [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). I use this XML with an XSL file. It worked fine until I got the Yen currency symbol (¥) from a database entry. This symbol is escaped to the `&yen;` HTML entity. This entity is breaking the XSL/XML engine:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Entity 'yen' not
>   defined in %file.xml%, line: %1% in %file.php% on line %2%

When the `&yen;` entity is not there everything works well.

Is there something I haven't done/included/configured to get this error?

Comment: The answer to your question title is yes, but according to your comments, that is not really what you're trying to find out. If you post some of your PHP code that is outputting the yen entity, we may be more able to help you. For example, what methods are you using to serialize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML only recognizes a few character entities: `&lt;`, `&gt;` `&quot;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`. Anything else would be a parsing error unless you add in definitions for the entities yourself: `<!ENTITY yen "&#x00a5">`

Answer (score 2):

With `&yen;` your XML becomes not well-formed XML, because XML doesn't have predefined `&yen;` entity. Valid escape version of `¥` is `&#xA5;`.

Comment: Yes I know that but why does DOMDocument escape it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to working with XML, the only entities that are defined by default are `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Any other entities need to be defined in the DTD.

XSL does not define any other entities in its doctype. Even if you're converting to (x)HTML, you don't have those other entities defined because your primary doctype is for XSL.

You *could* add a big bunch of declarations to define them in the DTD, but this would mean using a custom DTD, which isn't ideal, and is also a lot of work to maintain.

Frankly, the easiest solution to this is simply to use numeric entity code for everything. It's a pain, but it works in any XML dialect without needing any hacking with the DTD.

Comment: My problem is that is seems that the DOMDocument::createTextNode method is escaping automatically ¥ to &yen; thus breaking later the process...

Comment: @Alex: you might want to edit your question to clarify that you're asking why DOMDocument is outputting this entity... most people think you're asking why this entity is not allowed in XML.